# make[1]: *** [_build/app_error.o] Error 1

Tags: eclipse, makefile, nrf51

right now i use nrf51-dev kit and i want blinky code for that, in Keil i compile code and load in kit and it work fine but now i want to make code in eclipse, for that i install all required tool, but now it give me error in console is

```
echo  makefile
makefile
mkdir _build
Compiling file: app_error.c
The system cannot find the path specified.
make[1]: *** [_build/app_error.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Work/NRF/DOC/nRF51_SDK_7.1.0_372d17a/examples/ble_central/ble_app_multilink_central/pca10028/ser_s120_uart/armgcc'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

ant idea whay it happen or any solution for this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to reproduce and fix your problem here.

1. Keil and Eclipse don't use the same build system, and in this case, Eclipse uses the toolchain defined in your project's Makefile (nRF51_SDK_7.1.0_372d17a/examples/ble_central/ble_app_multilink_central/pca10028/ser_s120_uart/armgcc/makefile). That's why you have a different behavior than Keil (which uses an internal toolchain).
2. So, your project's makefile is trying to execute the following command :

   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<

...in which CC resolves as "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-gcc"

...in which GNU_INSTALL_ROOT is your toolchain's location, which you should fill by yourself (in nRF51_SDK_7.1.0_372d17a/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.windows). e.g.

> GNU_INSTALL_ROOT := $(PROGFILES)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.7 2013q1

3. These logs that you included come from the 'ser_s120_uart' project. If you want to build the blinky project, just import nRF51_SDK_7.1.0_372d17a/examples/peripheral/blinky to Eclipse.

Last but not least, don't forget the [Nordic community](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/questions/). Plenty of talented people there :)